# find data from row and put it in variables according to the occurrence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a log row that I need to get the first names text from it.
until now I used a "find_between" function, for example:

```
name1 = (find_between(row,'humblebrag1:{"firstName": "', '", "l'))  

name2 = (find_between(row,'humblebrag2:{"firstName": "', '", "l'))  

name3 = (find_between(row,'humblebrag3:{"firstName": "', '", "l'))
```

The problem is that now the data that I will get is going to be changed and the "humblebrag1,2,3" word that I used it with "find_between" and put it in a variable will be deleted from the row.

There is any other way to find any "first name" from this row and put it in variables according to the occurrence?
name1 will be the first "first name" that I found
name2 will be the second"first name" that I found and so on...

This is my input text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor amet mustache knausgaard +1 , blue bottle waistcoat tbh semiotics artisan synth stumptown gastropub cornhole celiac swag. Brunch raclette vexillologist post-ironic glossier ennui XOXO mlkshk godard pour-over blog tumblr humblebrag1:{"firstName": "Daniel", "lastName": "Danl", "age": 35},Lorem ipsum dolor amet mustache knausgaard +1 , blue bottle waistcoat tbh semiotics artisan synth stumptown gastropub cornhole celiac swag. Brunch raclette vexillologist post-ironic glossier ennui XOXO mlkshk godard pour-over blog tumblr humblebrag2:{"firstName": "Daniel2", "lastName": "Dan2", "age": 35},Lorem ipsum dolor amet mustache knausgaard +1, blue bottle waistcoat tbh semiotics artisan synth stumptown gastropub cornhole celiac swag. Brunch raclette vexillologist post-ironic glossier ennui XOXO mlkshk godard pour-over blog tumblr humblebrag3:{"firstName": "Daniel3", "lastName": "Dan3", "age": 35}

Comment: could you post the example input as text, not as an image? also, can you use `regex` or do you need a pure Python solution?

Comment: I tried but it didn't let me post it because "code syntax"..
And I can use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I get this right, your string contains data in `dict` format, i.e. key-value pairs bracketed by curly braces. To extract it, you could use a `regex.findall` to get all the respective substrings and then convert them to Python `dict` type using `ast.literal_eval`, e.g.

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor amet mustache knausgaard +1 , blue bottle waistcoat tbh semiotics artisan synth stumptown gastropub cornhole celiac swag. Brunch raclette vexillologist post-ironic glossier ennui XOXO mlkshk godard pour-over blog tumblr humblebragl:{"firstName": "Daniel", "lastName": "Danl", "age": 35},Lorem ipsum dolor amet mustache knausgaard +1 , blue bottle waistcoat tbh semiotics artisan synth stumptown gastropub cornhole celiac swag. Brunch raclette vexillologist post-ironic glossier ennui XOXO mlkshk godard pour-over blog tumblr humblebrag2:{"firstName": "Danie12", "lastName": "Dan2", "age": 35},Lorem ipsum dolor amet mustache knausgaard +1, blue bottle waistcoat tbh semiotics artisan synth stumptown gastropub cornhole celiac swag. Brunch raclette vexillologist post-ironic glossier ennui XOXO mlkshk godard pour-over blog tumblr humblebrag3:{"firstName": "Danie13", "lastName": "Dan3", "age": 35}'

results = re.findall('{.+?}', s)

if results:
    results = [literal_eval(r) for r in results]

for d in results:
    print(d['firstName'])
# Daniel
# Danie12
# Danie13
```